# How to add a box shadow to a css generated arrow?

Tags: html, css, border, box-shadow

I'm having difficulty adding a box shadow around the outline of the arrow that was generated using border properties. Is there a way to make the box shadow in the shape the same as the arrow instead of a square box?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/8f3j0kva/).

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a class="bx-prev"></a>
<a class="bx-next"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bx-prev, .bx-next {
  border-right: 15px solid green;
  border-bottom: 15px solid green;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.bx-prev {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
}
.bx-next {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the blur filter by creating the same arrow with a pseudo element:

```css
.bx-prev,
.bx-next {
  top: 200px;
  position:relative;
}

.bx-prev {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
}

.bx-next {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
}
/*the arrow*/
.bx-prev:before,
.bx-next:before,
.bx-prev:after,
.bx-next:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-right: 15px solid green;
  border-bottom: 15px solid green;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
/*the shadow*/
.bx-prev:after,
.bx-next:after{
  border-color: red;
  z-index:-1;
  filter:blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<a class="bx-prev"></a>
<a class="bx-next"></a>
```

Comment: This is exactly the effect i was looking for. Not a lot of browser support for the `filter:blur()` but hopefully in the future it will be. Thank you!

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight the filter is well supported actually https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters .. only IE fail which is not a surprise

Comment: I noticed in Firefox, it has a bug where the border rendering for arrows has a cut-through outline at the center point. Is there a fix for this? Check the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TheAmazingKnight/1cs2u798/ and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight try this way: https://jsfiddle.net/uf6m7k2e/ you won't have the issue

Comment: Thank you for the alternative. I got a simple fix from a another stackoverflow question adding the translateZ property for firefox: `transform: translatez(1px) rotate(45deg);`

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Edit!

```css
.bx-prev, .bx-next {
  border-right: 15px solid green;
  border-bottom: 15px solid green;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  top: 200px;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.7));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.7));
}
.bx-prev {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 220px;
}
.bx-next {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
}
```

```html
<a class="bx-prev"></a>
<a class="bx-next"></a>
```

Comment: I like this! This is pretty close, but I want to be around the entire arrow, not just the front, but behind it, too, if possible?